# EF core can't create Table, error in sql syntax

Tags: c#, .net-core, orm, entity-framework-core, mysql.data

im new to Entity framework and i dont understand why it is giving me an error in sql syntax , i thought the whole purpose of using EFCore is to handle the sql syntax and abstract all the sql queries away

here is my model :

```
  class Block 
    {
        public BlockHeader Header {get ;}
        public List<Transaction> Transactions {get;}

        public Block(List<Transaction> transactions, BlockHeader header)
        {
            Transactions= transactions;
            Header=header;           
        }    
        public Block(){
            
        }
    }
    public class BlockHeader
    {
        public byte[] Hash {get ;} 
        public byte[]  PreviousHash { get; }
        public DateTime timestamp { get; }
        public int version{ get; } 
        public byte[] MerkleRoot{ get; }
        public int SequenceNumber {get ; private set;}

        public BlockHeader (byte[] previoushash,int sequencenumber,List<Transaction> transactions)
        {
            timestamp = DateTime.Now;
            PreviousHash =  previoushash;
            version = 1;
            SequenceNumber = sequencenumber;
            MerkleRoot = ComputeMerkleRoot(transactions);
            Hash = ComputeBlockHash();

        }
```

and here is my database Context class

```
        class BlockchainDB : DbContext
        {
            public BlockchainDB()
            {
                
            }

            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database = Blockchain ;user = root ; password = password");
            }
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder){
                builder.Entity<Block>(e => e.HasNoKey());
            }   
        }
```

when i add a migration it adds it successfully but when i update the database using this command

```
dotnet ef database update
```

it outputs this error :

```
Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE `Block` (

);
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 3
```

Comment: @Bizhan EntityFramework does this , not me , i cant even find where the error is located

Comment: It's trying to create a table without any properties, this seems very incorrect. 
you don't have setters for your navigation properties.

if you try to encapsulate it, use a protected empty constructor, and private setters. 
I'm pretty sure the error can be found inside some of these pointers.

The erros is located in the generated SQL in 

`CREATE TABLE `Block` (
 -- this method won't work if empty. 
);`

Comment: Try adding DbSet<Block> to your DbContext class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EFCore entities needs setters, otherwise the reference will not be set.

I'd suggest you would write it something like this to ensure encapsulation

```
public class Block 
{
  protected Block()
  {
    // empty constructor needed for EF Core
  }

  // Navigation properties 
  public virtual BlockHeader BlockHeader {get; private set;}

  // For collections 
  private readonly List<ChildEntity> _children = new List<ChildEntity>();
  public virtual IReadOnlyList<ChildEntity> Children => _children.ToList();

  // Encapsulated Business logic constructor 
  public Block(BlockHeader header, List<ChildEntity> children)
  {
    _children = children;
    BlockHeader = header;
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can use the fluent api modelbuilder configuration through entity core framework and explicitly map the relations.

Comment: this solved it, the error disappeared , thank you sir ,now im trying to configure the relationship of blockheader in my Context class , i have new errors but i think i can find out whats the problem, thank you sir

Comment: Glad I could help. :) best of luck with the relation, if it's 1-1 relation between block and blockheader I would suggest using the fluent api, otherwise you'd have to annotate the dependant child class with the `[ForeignKey]` attribute.

Comment: im doing it with fluent api , thank you soo much sir